# Animate a ImageView Along a Custom Path in JavaFX

Tags: animation, javafx, path

I should create an application in **JavaFX** for a university project.

**The application permit to draw a line and a **ImageView** after, must follow this line.**

How can I realize that ?
Can someone please, tell me the classes that I must implement to realize this ?

the final result that I search is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQ5wqg10x_I).

Thank you so much in advance, I'm in difficulty :( .

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/package-summary.html

Comment: work through a tutorial on animations in javafx, apply what you learned, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not going as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'll do a minimal example in this day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PathTransition` to move the ImageView based on line you draw. This is a code example

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PathTransitionDemo extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Rectangle invisibleBorder = new Rectangle(600, 600);
        invisibleBorder.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        invisibleBorder.setLayoutX(-100);
        invisibleBorder.setLayoutY(-100);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (0, 0, 100, 100);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(0, 0));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(400, 0));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(400, 400));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0, 400));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(0, 0));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
        pathTransition.setNode(rect);
        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

        Button play = new Button("Play");
        play.setLayoutX(200);
        play.setLayoutY(200);
        play.setOnMouseClicked(event -> pathTransition.play());

        Group container = new Group(invisibleBorder, rect, path, play);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(container);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this example. 

I'll start from this to implement the application.